# Python Intro finger exercise

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code adds all but the last number in a sequence of decimal numbers in a string,with each number separated by a comma why is this so ?
if s=1.2,3.3,4.5 only first two numbers are added

```
s=input("Please enter a sequence of comma seperated decimal numbers: ")
a=""
ans=0
i=0
for c in s:
    if c!="," :
        a+=s[i]
    else:
        ans+=float(a)
        a=""
    i+=1    
    if i==len(s):
        break
print("The sum of numbers is =",ans)
```

Comment: Read your own code and try to execute it in your mind for the input `1,2`. When do you expect it to add `2`?

Comment: also:  `print(sum(map(float,s.split(","))))` .. consider using built-ins to split, apply a function to all elements of a list and sum your values. "Adding" to a string is bad in python, because it creates throwaway strings that do nothing but being created and destroyed again wich is not optimal for the time/space complexity of code

Answer (score 0):

Since (according to your code) the addition of a number occurs only when a `,` is found after it, and the last number doesn't have a `,` after it, it is not added to the result, so you should add it before the break statement:

```
for c in s:
    ...
    if i == len(s):
        ans += float(a)
        break
```

Another more Pythonic approach to this problem would be using `str.split`, `map`, and `sum`:

```
s = input("Please enter a sequence of comma seperated decimal numbers: ")
ans = sum(map(float, s.split(',')))
print("The sum of numbers is =", ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input("Please enter a sequence of comma seperated decimal numbers: ")
numLs = list(map(float, s.split(',')))
sum_ = sum(numLs)
print("The sum of numbers is =", sum_)
```

Try this hopefully it will work.